# I am not able to launch the ms edge in headless mode from js selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, microsoft-edge, headless, headless-browser

I am not able to launch the edge in headless mode in js (mocha+ chai) selenium. I am able to launch in non-headless mode and it is working as expected. PFB snippet which I am using to launch in headless mode. Am I missing anything here? Could you please help me out here to launch in headless mode? 88 is my edge version.

```js
edge = require('selenium-webdriver/edge');
headLessMode = true ;
driver = headLessMode ? new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.edge()).
setEdgeOptions(new edge.Options().addArguments(['--headless','--no-sandbox','--start-maximized','--window-size=1900,1080'])).build() :
new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.edge()).build();
```

Thanks!

Comment: What error are you getting

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try to set the options like below.

```
let options = new edge.Options(); 
options.setEdgeChromium(true); 
options.addArguments("headless");
```

See whether it works.